# Phase of limit as angular frequency approaches 0

Tags: limits

This problem is related to circuit analysis, but I'm having an issue with the math portion in particular.

I have this transfer function:

$$H(s)=\frac{0.3s^2+4s}{0.8s^2+18s+60}$$

I need to find the "low frequency limit," which means I plug in $s=j\omega$, and take the limit as $\omega\rightarrow0$

So I have the following equation:

$$H(j\omega)=\frac{0.3j^2\omega^2+4j\omega}{0.8j^2\omega^2+18j\omega+60}$$

And I'm trying to take this limit:
$$\lim_{\omega \to 0} H(j\omega)$$

I know the real part of the answer is simply 0, but I can't calculate the imaginary part.

How do I calculate the imaginary part?

EDIT:
I figured I can simplify this a bit to the following:
$$\lim_{\omega \to 0} \frac{4j\omega}{60+18j\omega}$$

EDIT2:

It says the answer is $0\angle90 °$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple.

$\lim_{\omega \to 0} \frac{4j\omega}{60+18j\omega}=0$. In polar form this can be expressed as $0\angle90°$.